# Adding dynamic sitemap to an angularJS application

Tags: angularjs, sitemap

I'm working on an AngularJS application which creates a lot of dynamic content, for example: Every time a new user is created a new link is generated, etc.

**Question:**

How can I manage all this in a sitemap, and is there any tool for automatically generating sitemaps in AngularJS? Do I have to update my sitemap each time a new user is registered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, I solved this problem by generating the sitemap at back end (Rest API) instead of Angular. I created a rest end point to generate a new sitemap, and return that in the form of an xml file. When the new sitemap was generated it contained all new dynamic urls, and there was no need to add a new url each time some content was updated

Comment: can you explain how to generate sitemap with Rest API?

Comment: To generate sitemap with rest api, follow the following steps:
1) Create a rest controller which returns a file
2) Create all the urls of your website, and store them in a file
3) Return the generated file as response fore rest call

Comment: Do you have script for that?

Comment: the urls are dynamic.

Comment: yes the URLs are dynamic, for example, for a specific item with id 1, the URL is "www.example.com/search/1" and many more dynamic URLs. Now at your Rest server you have full access of your database, and you know which URLs you should include in sitemap (only public URLs, like user profile edit urls etc should be in sitemap). So you just have to write code and append different dynamic fields from your database and make a string just like you have one url and add it in your file

Comment: ok. Thanks. do you have any idea about this https://www.npmjs.com/package/sitemap?

Comment: This is a front-end sitemap generator library. I went through the same confusion whether I should generate my sitemap on front-end or back-end. The answer is these libraries work well for non-dynamic sites. It might generate a sitemap containing only the static pages of your site. For example "www.example.com/contact" etc, but it can't generate dynamic pages. So that's why I shifted my sitemap generation login to my back-end(Rest server) which is a bit tricky, but the right solution in case of dynamic URLs

Comment: Thanks you so much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142806/discussion-between-vel-and-muhammad-ahsan).

Comment: I have one doubt in springboot. can you help with this?

Comment: Hi. I created sitemap with REST API as well, but I don't know how to display it correctly on angular side. I tried to redirect to api endpoint but google still says that it is incorrect (html) format.

Answer (score 0):

We work with 1000s of relevant urls at our startup. As people said here and elsewhere, you want to have a static sitemap.xml which gets regularly updated (every day or every few days) and thus include all new relevant urls.

If you are working in a Javascript environment such as Angular and don't want to use any libraries or frameworks, look at this article here for a plain Javascript solution to create a sitemap accessing a database, getting all the urls, then creating the xml and getting you the file - which you can then plug into your site structure.

https://www.epiloge.com/how-to-generate-a-sitemapxml-with-javascript-for-dynamic-page-urls-296c42

Comment: @Can you please let me know how I can plug this xml into my angular 9 site structure?